# CW complexes and manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, cw-complexes

What is the strongest known theorem (if any) that classify which manifolds can be built as CW complexes?
Thank you guys. This is just  a question I thought of during class, obviously not homework...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Smooth closed manifolds can always be given a CW structure via Morse functions, but one has to be careful in constructing the attaching maps (for instance, one must choose a regular neighborhood of the $k$-skeleton and perturb the gradient flow to define attaching maps for the $(k+1)$-cells). For more details, see the answers to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11375/cw-structures-and-morse-functions-a-reference-request) MathOverflow question, especially Ryan Budney's.

Closed topological manifolds of dimension other than four are homeomorphic to CW complexes. The reference is Kirby-Siebenmann, *On the triangulation of manifolds and the Hauptvermutung*, Bull AMS 75 (1969). My reference for this is (again) Ryan Budney's answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36838/are-non-pl-manifolds-cw-complexes) MathOverflow question. The comments to the answer and to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73428/when-is-a-compact-topological-4-manifold-a-cw-complex) MO question indicate that Kirby-Siebenmann prove that every compact (top) manifold of dimension other than $4$ is indeed a CW complex, but the question is still open in dimension 4. (Another comment points to [these](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/slides/orsay.pdf) slides by A. Ranicki.)

I'm not sure how the classification proceeds for open manifolds.

Answer (score 24):

This is an addendum to Neal's answer (concerning the 4-dimensional case):

1. Every connected noncompact 4-manifold admits a PL structure, hence, a triangulation (F.Quinn, "Ends of maps-III", 1982).
2. For compact 4-manifolds the problem of existence of a CW-complex (as well as a handlebody) structure is open, see Question 1.3 in [this list of problems](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Questions_about_surgery_theory).