# Manifolds and CW-complexes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

This is a very naive question. Every manifold (assumed to be paracompact) is a CW-complex?

Thanks.

Comment: Using Morse theory one can show that a smooth manifold is homotopic to a CW complex.

Comment: Better than that, @Seth, they all actually are CW complexes. (Instead of contracting the handlebody diagram down to the cores, just give the handles a workable CW structure; that or just pick a triangulation.) I think topological manifolds are all homotopy equivalent to CW complexes. If you google this question you should find some MO questions that help.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593041/cw-complexes-and-manifolds