# Is a compact connected manifold-with-boundary a CW complex?

Tags: cw-complexes, manifolds-with-boundary, compact-manifolds

Suppose $M$ is a compact connected manifold-with-boundary with non-empty boundary. What can be said on whether $M$ can be given a CW complex structure?

A similar problem has been discussed for compact connected manifolds (i.e. with empty boundary) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593041/cw-complexes-and-manifolds), where it is true for $\dim \neq 4$ and not known for $\dim = 4$. Suppose the case for $\dim = 4$ is also shown true someday. Can the case with non-empty boundary be reduced to the case with empty boundary; i.e. are these problems equivalent?